# How to find correct projection of the shapefile data for leaflet map in r?

Tags: r, leaflet, geospatial, projection, r-sf

I am new to **geo spatial** data & trying to create **choropleth map** using **leaflet** & **shapefile**.

I have tried to plot the data on **leaflet map** but getting an error: **Error: Must supply `x`/`y` attributes** which seems to be due to some **projection issues** & not sure how to correct the projections in accordance with **leaflet()**.

**My shapefile Projections**

```
ind_global$geometry %>% 
  st_crs()
```

output:

```
  User input: WGS 84 
  wkt:
GEOGCRS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",
        ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
        ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    CS[ellipsoidal,2],
        AXIS["latitude",north,
            ORDER[1],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
        AXIS["longitude",east,
            ORDER[2],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    ID["EPSG",4326]]
```

```
library(raster)

crs(ind_global$geometry)
```

`CRS arguments: +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs`

(**UPDATE:**

Link to geometry dataset `ind_global`: https://github.com/johnsnow09/covid19-df_stack-code/blob/main/ind_global_rds.rds
)

**Code I tried:**

```
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)
libraary(leaflet)
library(htmlwidgets)

pal <- colorBin(palette = "OrRd", 9, domain = ind_global$total_vaccinations)
```

```
ind_global %>% 
  st_as_sf() %>% 
  st_transform(crs = "+init=epsg:4326") %>% 
  leaflet() %>% 
  addProviderTiles(provider = "CartoDB.Positron") %>% 
  add_polygons(label = Country.Region,
               stroke = FALSE,
               smoothFactor = .5,
               opacity = 1,
               fillOpacity = 0.7,
               fillColor = ~ pal(total_vaccinations),
               highlightOptions = highlightOptions(weight = 5,
                                                   fillOpacity = 1,
                                                   bringToFront = TRUE)) %>% 
  
  addLegend("bottomright",
            pal = pal,
            values = ~ total_vaccinations,
            title = "total Vaaccinations",
            opacity = 0.7)
```

**Also tried with below projections but getting error:**

`st_transform(crs = "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs")`

`st_transform(crs = "+proj=longlat +ellps=GRS80")`

---

The **Shape file** when plotted using **ggplot** & **geom_sf()**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this issue at least when I ran your code is that Country.Region is a factor and not a character variable.  I made just a few edits to your code and got what I think you are after:

```
library(sf)
library(leaflet)
library(htmlwidgets)
library(riskyr)

ind_global<-readRDS("C:/Users/SCMCKENZIE/Downloads/ind_global_rds.rds")

pal <- colorBin(palette = "OrRd", 9, domain = ind_global$total_vaccinations)

tmp<-ind_global %>% 
  st_as_sf() %>% 
  st_transform(crs = "+init=epsg:4326")
tmp %>% leaflet() %>% 
  addProviderTiles(provider = "CartoDB.Positron") %>% 
  addPolygons(label = as.character(tmp$Country.Region),
               stroke = FALSE,
               smoothFactor = .5,
               opacity = 1,
               fillOpacity = 0.7,
               fillColor = ~ pal(total_vaccinations),
               highlightOptions = highlightOptions(weight = 5,
                                                   fillOpacity = 1,
                                                   bringToFront = TRUE)) %>% 
  
  addLegend("bottomright",
            pal = pal,
            values = ~ total_vaccinations,
            title = "total Vaaccinations",
            opacity = 0.7)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Sean but I am not sure if that's the issue because before raising the post here I tried the code by commenting `label = Country.Region` which didn't work & now I ran my original code with an edit of `label = as.character(Country.Region)` & it still didnt work. But when I run ur code that saves data as an object first works perfectly. So really appreciate ur help as ur code is working perfectly !!

Comment: I think referring the variable as part of the data frame is the necessity: `tmp$Country.Region` otherwise it gives an error which is strange as another variable `total_vaccination` is being used in this function without mentioning dataframe$var. Sometimes I dont get r functions at all & also in there help nothing is mentioned

Comment: My guess why using `tmp$Country.Region` is necessary, although I'm not sure if this is true, is that you can't coerce variables to new datatypes using the `%>%` piping syntax with out explicitly defining it from the dataframe using the `$`.  I have run into this with ``tidyverse` packages.  `Tidyverse` has a lot of great functionality, but I think it kind of assumes everyone using it is a computer programmer and some of those quirks are self evident.  Not being a programmer myself, I run into these roadblocks frequently.

Comment: Yeah, I totally agree with you. I am also not a programmer so I am facing these challenges every other day !!